# About change AUTH_USER_MODEL and customize the built-in User model

Tags: django, django-models, django-authentication

The doc says" **If you intend to set AUTH_USER_MODEL, you should set it before creating any migrations or running manage.py migrate for the first time.**".
So i want to double check about this, and is it possible to change the built-in User model the DB setup?

Answer (score 1):

You can create your own user model rather than changing the built-in one. That's what `AUTH_USER_MODEL` does. It tells django to use *your* user model as the default, rather than the default `django.contrib.auth.models.User`.

You should do this once in the beginning of the project and then stick with whatever you have setup; as this setting has effects for many other areas of the framework. That is why there is a warning in the documentation.

Comment: thanks for your reply. The problem is that I realized the built-in User model does not suffice our needs only after some previous work. So it's too late to create another User model now?

Comment: This depends on data that exists in the database. When you change the user model to a custom one, it'll create new database table, so any rows in the default Django auth_user tables isn't moved over. This can also create orphaned rows in other tables unless you're comfortable with massaging the data manually. If you're okay with starting fresh data-wise, then you're fine, for example, if you're still not in production.